# Why does date_range give a result different from indexing [] for DataFrame Pandas dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a simple code with `date_range` and indexing [ ] I used with Pandas

```
period_start = '2013-01-01'
period_end = '2019-12-24'

print(pd.DataFrame ({'close':aapl_close,
        'returns':aapl_returns},index=pd.date_range(start=period_start,periods=6)))

print(pd.DataFrame ({'close':aapl_close,
            'returns':aapl_returns})[period_start:'20130110'])
```

`date_range` gives Nan results

```
            close  returns
2013-01-01    NaN      NaN
2013-01-02    NaN      NaN
2013-01-03    NaN      NaN
2013-01-04    NaN      NaN
```

Indexing gives correct results

```
                            close   returns
2013-01-02 00:00:00+00:00  68.732  0.028322
2013-01-03 00:00:00+00:00  68.032 -0.010184
2013-01-04 00:00:00+00:00  66.091 -0.028531
```

Based on how the dates are shown by `date_range` - I suppose the date format of `date_range` does not match the date format in the Pandas DataFrame.

1) Can you explaine please why it gives NaN?

2) What would you suggest to get a specific time range from the Panda DataFrame?

Comment: What is `aapl_close`?

Comment: Hi ALollz, it's the close prices for AAPL stock price. You can get it from Pandas library. I just didn't page all the code, as In thought no need to

Answer (score 1):

As I'm a beginner in Python and its libraries, I didn't understand that this question refers to the Quantopian library, not to Pandas.

I got a solution on their forum. All the times returned by methods on Quantopian are timezone aware with a timezone of 'UTC'. By default, the date_range method returns timezone naive dates. Simply supply the timezone information to date_range method. Like this

```
pd.DataFrame ({  
'close':aapl_close,  
'returns':aapl_returns,},  
index=pd.date_range(start=period_start, periods=6, tz='UTC'))
```

To get a specific date or time range in pandas perhaps the easiest is simple bracket notation. For example, to get dates between 2013-01-04 and 2013-01-08 (inclusive) simply enter this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'close':aapl_close,  'returns':aapl_returns,})  
my_selected_dates = df['2013-01-04':'2013-01-08']
```

This bracket notation is really shorthand for using the loc method

```
my_selected_dates = df.loc['2013-01-04':'2013-01-08']
```

Both work the same but the loc method has a bit more flexibility. This notation also works with datetimes if desired.